# D3.js: Making a line and the d-object is undefined in a function calling an attribute on the path-element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, undefined

I have a a problem with the d-object being undefined when I'm creating the line and I'm then trying to implement a function on the line, changing the stroke-attribute's colors.

The problematic section is this one:

```
var myLine = mySVG.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line(ourValues))  // by changing this to myData one can get the unsorted data plotted instead, this is the attribut theat connects the paths to a certain object/array
    .attr("stroke", function (d) {console.log("what is this"); console.log(d); return "red";});
```

I tried to console.log the value to see what goes on when I couldn't get my functions to work.

I use v3 of d3.js but putting it into JSfiddle with the v4-library I still couldn't get it to work so the problem is  that I don't understand where my data goes and how to retrieve it in this case.

My fiddle of it:

https://jsfiddle.net/jstz8fwq/

(the problem is on line 82 in the fiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3, the first argument (traditionally named `d`) is the datum (singular of data) bound to that element.

However, you have no data bound here:

```
var myLine = mySVG.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line(ourValues))
```

If we change the code and actually bind data to that element:

```
var myLine = mySVG.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .datum(ourValues)
    .attr("d", line)
```

You'll see the `data` in the console. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/92y46y48/

Comment: Thank you! I did earlier try 
"var myLine = mySVG.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .data(ourValues)
  .attr("d", line(ourValues)) 
  .attr("stroke", function (d) {console.log("what is this"); console.log(d); return "red";});"
but that didn't work and I don't really get why, can you explain that?
It just gives me the first line of the object.

Comment: That's because you used `.data(ourValues)`, and I used `.datum(ourValues)`.